# .libPaths not accurately directing install.packages

Tags: r, path, rstudio, install.packages

I am confused!

I have just done a R and Rstudio reinstall on a work computer (where I am not administrator). I have added to the Environmental Variables R_LIBS_USER = "C:/Users/USER.NAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"as the location for my library.

at the console when I type:

```
.libPaths()
```

It returns:

```
[1] "C:/Users/USER.NAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program        Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"
```

As I read the the install.packages should default to install to the first path. However, when I run

```
install.packages("the package")
```

or

```
 install.packages("the package", lib = "C:/Users/USER.NAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.2")
```

it returns:

```
Error in install.packages : path[1]="C:\Users\USER.NAME\Documents\.Rhistory\win-library\3.2": The system cannot find the path specified
```

it seems that ".Rhistory" is replacing "R" in the path.  Why?

```
> sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1